# Unable to get Ankhsvn to connect to VisualSVN

Tags: visual-studio, svn, ankhsvn

I know this question has been asked before, but I've been through loads of suggested answers and none seem to work.

I have installed VisualSVN 2.7.3.  This appears to work fine (the Management Console opens and allowed me to create a new Repository).

I have installed AnkhSVN 2.5.  This too appeared to go well, and I have all the menus I'd expect in Visual Studio 11.

Now I have the problem that has been posted before: I cannot add an existing Solution to the Repository.  If I use View | Repository Explorer and type the URL shown in VisualSVN Management Console (which is of the form `https://PC_NAME/SVN/<repository_name>/`), it appears to do this without error; however, it shortens the URL to `https://PC_NAME/`.

I am wondering if I have locked myself out by creating a user with a password when setting up VisualSVN.  I expected AnkhSVN to ask me for these login credentials at some point, but it hasn't.

I realize this question is a bit vague, but any help would be very much appreciated.

Kind wishes ~ Patrick